# sintaxis de or en php

Tags: php

Tengo esta condicion en php

```
if ($Parametros[1] != "Pedidos" or $Parametros[1] != "Presupuestos") { }
```

La idea es que si `$Parametros[1]` no es `"Pedidos"` o `"Presupuestos"` que se ejecute lo que quede dentro de los corchetes.

por algún motivo no me funciona :( he probado a ponerlo entre paréntesis pero tampoco

```
if (($Parametros[1] != "Pedidos")or($Parametros[1] != "Presupuestos")) {
```

si le pongo una sola condición si funciona, pero con el `or` no.

```
if ($Parametros[1] != "Pedidos") { }
```

¿que tengo mal en la condición para que no se ejecute?

Comment: Cuando dices que "no funciona", ¿qué quieres decir? Pero te diré que lógicamente, no es un `OR` lo que quieres, porque si verificas la lógica, verás que tu `IF` siempre evaluará a `true`. Probablemente es un `AND` lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> La idea es que si $Parametros[1] no es "Pedidos" o "Presupuestos" que
>   se ejecute lo que quede dentro de los corchetes.

Tu lógica está mal ,Usted está preguntando si el valor de una elemento de un array no es `Pedidos` o No `Presupuestos`. Si es `Pedidos`, definitivamente tampoco es `Presupuestos` y si es `Presupuestos` definitivamente no es `Pedidos`. Por lo tanto, esa afirmación siempre devuelve `true`.

El operador lógico debería ser un `and` para que evalué las dos condiciones.

```
if ($Parametros[1] != "Pedidos" and $Parametros[1] != "Presupuestos" )
```

Comment: pues si, era eso XD. hay días que uno no esta inspirado y no ve algo tan básico